# Can you configure the Docker daemon to expose istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer

Tags: docker, istio, docker-desktop, knative

I am running Knative/Istio in minikube(docker driver) on a mac computer with docker for mac

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.104.16.88   localhost     15021:30057/TCP,80:31309/TCP,443:31753/TCP,15012:31321/TCP,15443:31887/TCP   14d
```

Is it possible to Configure the Docker daemon in any way so I can expose the "EXTERNAL-IP localhost to the host machine.
And then further expose the host machine to a dns server to access container apps in kubernetes?

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "127.0.0.1"]
}
```

To be able to do `myapp.default.mydomain.com` into kubernetes within the minikube on the host machine

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `minikube tunnel` this will allocate an EXTERNAL-IP that is reachable from the host. for more info check the minkube [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/)